# Different BIOS versions are displayed - in the BIOS menu and in the motherboard update program

Tags: motherboard, bios

The `msinfo32` and "MSI live update" displays the 2.80 version.

The BIOS menu displays the 2.61 version.

**Questions:**

1. Why is that and what does it mean? May be, it means that BIOS was updated by previous owner?
2. Is it possible to find out whether this is the original BIOS installed by the manufacturer, or it was updated by someone? (I mean in general, not only in this particular case).

[image]

[image]

#### EDIT

I have looked into the "System Information" submenu in the BIOS and it has the 2.80 version. So, the main page of menu displayes 2.61, but the submenu gives 2.80.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect the v2.61 in the BIOS screen is merely a textual bug.  The BIOS programmers probably forgot to update that text string.  Elsewhere in the BIOS, Windows, and the BIOS update utility say its v2.8.

You can check the computer or motherboard manufacturer's website for BIOS updates.  Sometimes they list older BIOS updates, sometimes with a list of fixes included.  However, I doubt a simply text string might not get mentioned for an update.  Unfortunately, that machine is so old, based on the CPU, you might not have much luck finding older BIOS versions.  You can always flash it with the latest BIOS.

I wouldnt worry about it, if the machine is working properly.